# JDBC: Could not create statement

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I'm trying to execute a Query through JDBC against a Oracle DB. I've verified that it works in SQL Developer.
But when I run it through JDBC I get a "null" value on

```
ps = con.prepareStatement(sql.toString());
```

I've tried different statements and SQL queries, all work in the SQL developer bur non in JDBC. Also, I do not get any stacktrace to debug on to..

Query1

```
      sql.append("SELECT * FROM Tabel WHERE (ID1=" + id + " AND ORG=" + org + ") OR (ID2=" + id + " AND ORG=" + org + ")");
```

Query2

```
sql.append("SELECT * FROM Tabel WHERE (ID1=" + id + " OR ID2=" + id + ") AND ORG=?" + org);
```

Query3

```
sql.append("SELECT * FROM Tabel WHERE (ID1=? OR ID2=?) AND ORG=?");
ps = con.prepareStatement(sql.toString());
ps.setString(1, id);
ps.setString(2, id);
ps.setString(3, org);
```

The code

```
try {
  log.debug("Creating Query");
  StringBuffer sql = new StringBuffer();
  sql.append("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE (ID1=? OR ID2=?) AND ORG=?");
  log.debug("Query created: " + sql.toString()); //Don't get here
  ps = con.prepareStatement(sql.toString());
  ps.setString(1, id);
  ps.setString(2, id);
  ps.setString(3, org);
  log.debug("Query Created!!!!");
  con = getConnection();
} catch (Exception e) {
  log.error("Could not create statement in methodXXX");
  //Returns null in e.getMessage()
  throw new Exception("Could not create query: " + e.getMessage()); 
}
```

//Henrik

Comment: Where exactly you are trying to execute? As far as I see you just set up parameter values.

Comment: And what is `sql` before you append to it?

Comment: query 3 is good practice and it should work

Comment: Can you show use more code? Creation of the connection etc.

Comment: The sql is a String bugger that create a string to inject to the ps = con.prepareStatement(sql.toString()); statement and I do not get passed that line, where the prepareStatment is ran, the querys are the different "Strings" I've tried to create statements for.

The following is working..
sql.append("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ID1=? AND ORG=?");

Comment: There should be spance between Table and Where clause in 'SELECT * FROM TabelWHERE ....' statement.

Comment: The space is there in my code, a typo in the question. //Henrik

Comment: Is it possible to use the same attribute "id", twice in a query using the setString method?

Comment: What is your sql.toString() value it fails to create prepared statement for? May be it contains some litter from other queries or something?

Comment: JDBC only allows (by specification) a single query to be executed by a statement, not three concatenated queries (and if it was allowed, the way you do it, is wrong because you don't separate the queries in any way)

Comment: Also, if you use a `PreparedStatement`, then use it correctly: use parameter placeholders, don't concatenate the values into the query.

Comment: I've added the code, but is there a big difference in using the ps.setString and having a array with the values in the prepareStatment?

Comment: it's rather unusual you can't get to the line log.debug("Query created: " + sql.toString()); //Don't get here 
Do you get any exceptions?

Comment: That's the weird part, the exception is null.

Comment: does it work if you skip StringBuffer part and just provide sql statement as as string directly into prepareStatement() ?

Comment: Show us how you create the connection object. Wait - why do you first create the prepared statement and _then_ you get the connection?

Comment: and does it pass this line log.debug("Creating Query"); at all?
May be your log variable is not initialized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply use following way

```
ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Tabel WHERE (ID1=? OR ID2=?) AND ORG=?");
ps.setString(1, id);
ps.setString(2, id);
ps.setString(3, org)
ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
while(rs.next())
{
//use your code to retrieve like rs.getString(1);
}
```